# IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest not called in some SOAP services

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, iis, endpointbehavior

I have several WCF SOAP services that programmatically expose an endpoint to which an [`IEndPointBehavior`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) is attached.

```
var endpoint = AddServiceEndpoint(contractType,
                                  basicBinding,
                                  address);
_logger.Write("Adding behavior for service {0}, contract: {1}", serviceName, cd.Value.ContractType);
endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyBehavior());
```

In the behavior class, I add a message inspector to the Dispatch runtime:

```
void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, 
        EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
{
    _logger.WriteError("Adding Inspector to endpoint {0}, contract {1}", endpoint.Address.ToString(), endpoint.Contract.Name);

    endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new MyInspector());
}
```

In the message inspector, I implemented the `AfterReceiveRequest` method like:

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    _logger.WriteError("AfterReceiveRequest for {0} via {1}", request.Headers.Action, request.Properties.Via);
     // implementation omitted...
     return null;
}
```

Now I can see the 'Adding behavior' and 'Adding inspector' log messages for all my services, but the `AfterReceiveRequest` method is only called for some services.

The services for which the method is not called are running under a different web application in IIS, but I cannot find anything different that would explain why this inspector would not work.
The services in which the inspector is not working are also deriving from a different base class, but I ripped out all the code from that base class and still the method is not called.

I turned on message tracing and do see that the client is calling the correct endpoint.

Does anyone have an idea why this may happen or how I can better debug this?

Comment: Do you say that it's not being called because you don't see the logs? Maybe the different web app in IIS doesn't have write permissions to the log? If you replace the `_logger.WriteError(...)` call with something that would cause a crash (`throw new Exception`), does the call from the client, which used to succeed, starts failing?

Comment: No, it's not the logging (which goes to SQL). I've inserted Debugger.Launch() statements there and they do not execute either for that web application. Is there any condition under which the AfterReceiveRequest method for an endpoint behavior would not be called? I can't debug the WCF framework itself, so I can't set a breakpoint. Any advise on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: @carlosfigueira I found the issue (see the answer I posted). WIF code blocking the pipeline. Do you think it's okay if I add the code of the modified tool on Github? I'll make sure to attribute it to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem with my code. Both WCF services have a WIF (.NET 4.5) [`ClaimsAuthorizationManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthorizationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) attached. The call to [`CheckAccess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthorizationmanager.checkaccess(v=vs.110).aspx) was returning `true` for one service and `false` for the other. The one where it was returning false, never went on to call the `AfterReceiveRequest` of the endpoint behavior.

I extended Carlos Figueira's incredibly useful [commandline tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/18/wcf-extensibility-runtime.aspx) with a WIF `ClaimsAuthenticationManager` and `ClaimsAuthorizationManager` and found that their `Authenticate` and `CheckAccess` methods are called before the `AfterReceiveRequest` on the `DispatchMessageInspector`.

As I needed an extension point that was called before the CheckAccess, I ended up using a class implementing [`IInstanceContextProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstancecontextprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

But I made it work without implementing IInstanceContextProvider..
Just hookup your inspector object through contractbehavior instead of endpoint behavior.

Comment: Any example how to do this?